# PHP Exceptions - Proper Error Handling

Tags: php, error-handling, try-catch, php-5.5

What is the proper way to handle `exceptions` in `PHP`? Should you literally:

```
try{} catch($e){}
try{} catch($e){}
try{} catch($e){}
try{} catch($e){}
try{} catch($e){}
try{} catch($e){}
try{} catch($e){}
```

Like, should you even `try, catch` inside other `try, catch`? E.g.

```
try{
      try{} catch($e){}
} catch($e){
}
```

I'm a little confused to what extend you should `try, catch` .. or rather how most `PHP` programmers do it. Since as soon as you `catch` an `exception` it usually cancels out the rest of the code, which seems to me that you can't avoid using tonnes of nested `try{} catch($e){}` am I wrong?

**UPDATE:**

http://codepad.org/RFqBsAKv

Comment: Try attempts to execute everything within a given block of code. The exception will fire if anything fails within that block of code. There is no reason for nested try/catch.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Well, the issue is that in some cases it seems inevitable to use nested `try, catch` unless i'm tripping. :-/

Comment: Can you create a mock condition where it would be more appropriate? Maybe with specific custom error handlers for database queries, or something.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Added codepad link.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Meh, that is a horrible example. I'm working on a really advanced project and it just seems inevitable. Maybe, I should just think about it a bit more.